# How do I add text inside of an input field using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, input

This should be easy, but nothing seems to work. I have a jQuery function that contains two parameters. The first parameter (pageID) is supposed to be inserted into a hidden field. It works correctly. I want the second parameter to be inserted into an html input field. That is, I want to see the contents of the parameter 'pageName' inside the form field as if I had just typed it in myself. Here is the code:

```
function insertIntoHiddenField(pageID,pageName)
{
    $('input[name=page_id]').val(pageID);
    $('input[name=page_name]').val(pageName);
}
```

When I look at the source code, I find that the value attribute in the input tag contains the value from the parameter 'pageName'. But, the input field itself is empty. I want to see that value in the input field. What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I also tried (without success) the following:

```
$('input[name=page_name]').text(pageName);
$('input[name=page_name]').innerhtml(pageName);
$('input[name=page_name]').append(pageName);
```

Comment: Can you post [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce this problem? Because your code looks like it should work, so I strongly suspect that something else is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Give an `id` to the hidden element. Just to be on the safe side and use `.val()`

```
$('#page_name').val('newtext');
$('#page_id').val('newtext');
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/9qU9A/1/)

However, your method works perfectly for me. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/9qU9A/)

Comment: That's not really the safe side. That's the only side ;)

Comment: and how this answers his question ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, It provides an alternative to his `how to add text` question and tell him that his method are also working at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! Using an id instead of the name attribute made it work. Not sure why, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Check your input html is valid, this example works.

```
<input name=​"page_name" type=​"text" value=​"">​

$("input[name=page_name]").val() == "" // true
$("input[name=page_name]").val("a")
$("input[name=page_name]").val() == "a" // true
```